# Change color in categorized layer?

Tags: qgis

I am kinda new to QGIS and am wondering how to change colors when vector layers are categorised but keep the order in the legend? I need to do this because I am making a map with different stages or progreessed represented though phase 1-5. All I want to do is change the vector layers from phase 3 to phase 4. Is there a way to do it with Python because I want to try and use that a little bit to get some experience using it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html  Look in this webpage, towards the end of the webpage.  It should guide you through it.  I don't see a need for Python for the simple task you describe.